# How can I detect I am running in a chroot() environment without being UID 0?

Tags: c, linux, detection, privileges, chroot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting a chroot jail from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75182/detecting-a-chroot-jail-from-within)

Detecting whether your process is executed in a chroot() environment on Linux is relatively easy: by comparing the device/inode of /proc/1/root and /. However, that requires access to stat() on /proc/1/root -- which is unfortunately privileged.

I am looking for a nice way to achieve the same thing, but without requiring privileges for that. Anybody can help me? How can my unprivileged code detect whether its is being executed in a chroot() environment?

Comment: Hmm. This might belong to unix.SE

Comment: @user: We've got you locked inside a chroot inside a user-mode linux instance inside a VM.  It was the only way to arrange a triple kick.

Comment: Why was this closed as "exact duplicate"? The supposed exact duplicate does not cover things for UID != 0. The folks who closed this as duplicate didn't even bother to read my question.

Comment: This answer describe how to detect chroot without root privileges : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8070267/301717

Answer (score 4):

If you found one, you should report it as a bug.  The whole point of *chroot()* is to let someone make a protected environment that doesn't give away that hint without privilege.

Comment: Can't risk our bio-batteries realizing they're just slaves in the matrix, can we?

Comment: Clearly, the right answer is "take the blue pill".

Comment: chroot() is not really a security tool. At least not if used without anything else. You can trivially escape a chroot() by doing chrooting back to /../ or something similar. It just shifts around what "/" means, but that doesn't really have much to do with security.